# Conda proxyeroor when shadowsocks opening

Tags: anaconda

I tried to using conda to install tensorflow, but conda show an `ProxyError` when shadowsocks opening. Though I have configured the `proxy_servers` in `.condarc` with the `http:\\localhost:port`, it did not work. Meanwhile, the `direct` mode didn't work too. Only I turn off the Shadowsocks, can conda link to channels.

Hers is the Error Message.

`ProxyError: Conda cannot proceed due to an error in your proxy configuration. Check for typos and other configuration errors in any '.netrc' file in your home directory, any environment variables ending in '_PROXY', and any other system-wide proxy configuration settings.`

How can I use conda normally without turning off shadowsocks?